# How to map an object to objectDTO with nested lists of objects in C#, using Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to create a mapping profile of an object with two nested lists of objects, using AutoMapper. In the mapping profile I can map an object to objectDTO, but I have not found a way to map its lists too.

```
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Project, ProjectDTO>().ReverseMap();
        //CreateMap<Project, ProjectDTO>().ForMember(dto => dto.ProjectCategoryDTOs, c => c.MapFrom(c => c.ProjectCategories.Select(cat => cat.Category))).ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<ProjectCategory, ProjectCategoryDTO>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ProjectImage, ProjectImageDTO>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }


public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Intro { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    // Many to Many
    public virtual List<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProjectCategory>();
    // One to Many
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectImage> ProjectImages { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping without Automapper:

```
            var project = await applicationDbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == id)
                .Include(pc => pc.ProjectCategories).ThenInclude(c => c.Category)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            ProjectDTO projectDTO = new ProjectDTO()
            {
                Id = project.Id,
                Name = project.Name,
                Intro = project.Intro,
                Description = project.Description,
                ProjectCategoryDTOs = project.ProjectCategories.Select(x => new ProjectCategoryDTO()
                {
                    Category = mapper.Map<Category, CategoryDTO>(x.Category),
                    CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                    Project = mapper.Map<Project, ProjectDTO>(x.Project),
                    ProjectId = x.ProjectId
                }).ToList(),
                ProjectImageDTOs = project.ProjectImages.Select(x => new ProjectImageDTO()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                    ProjectDTO = mapper.Map<Project, ProjectDTO>(x.Project),
                    ProjectImageUrl = x.ProjectImageUrl,
                }).ToList(),
            };
            return projectDTO;
```

I would like to use a mapping profile to map the objects and not not repeat myself. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `CreateMap<Project, ProjectDTO>().ForMember(dto => dto.ProjectCategoryDTOs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectCategories)).ForMember(dto => dto.ProjectImageDTOs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectImages)).ReverseMap();` Looks like you will need to do the same type of member mapping on your ProjectCategoryDTO and ProjectImageDTO

Comment: I had tried something similar but had passed the wrong class. Thank your very much. Your suggestion works and is the right answer.